# How to add two 40 digit numbers in Objective-C and Android

Tags: android, objective-c

I want to know how to add two 40 digit numbers both in Objective C and Android.

Example:

```
 4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
+5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How to store and where to store these values?

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of objective-c, following code is been used to do the calculation

```
NSDecimalNumber *aNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]; 

NSDecimalNumber *bNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]; 

NSDecimalNumber *cNumber = [aNumber decimalNumberByAdding:bNumber]; 

NSLog(@"%@", cNumber);
```

here we use the NSDecimalNumber.

Answer (score 2):

In Android you can use the [BigInteger](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html) class for arbitrary sized integers. As for storing them, depends on what you need to store them for, but android has a number of storage options described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) that should be able to store these large integers.